# "win-x86" or "win-x64" target runtime for Any CPU?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-5

Many years I have built my apps under "Any CPU" configuration. But I have update to .Net 5, decide to use the Publish Function, which asking to implicitly choose between "win-x86" and "win-x64" options for target runtime.

I thought the whole deal with the "Any CPU" was to built apps not choosing between x86 and x64?  What should I do now?

[image: Publish menu]

Comment: This is probably because `self-contained` means that the runtime is embedded, so you have to pick which runtime should be embedded.

Comment: @riQQ But "framework-dependent" version also asks about target runtime :) The only difference is that the "portable" option appears in that list.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: @Vega So, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860621/what-are-differences-between-portable-and-win-x64-when-deploying), for example, should be out too?

Comment: @Vega Programming Tools (like Visual Studio) are on topic here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic:  "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Answer (score 2):

When publishing the app, a target architecture needs to be specified, because the compiler will create an architecture specific stub loader for the project (in Windows, the "exe" file).

In .NET Core, all C# projects (irrespective of whether they're applications or libraries) compile to .dll files. These .dll files are platform independent, or AnyCPU (of course unless they contain code that would only run on certain operating systems, such as P/Invoke calls). The applications compiled this way can be run by using the `dotnet <DllName>` command.

Now this is not convenient, because people expect an "exe" file to start a program with. This exe file (or an equivalent "no-extension" file for unix) is created by the publish command, in addition to copying everything together. The exe file with the same name as the main .dll is the stub-loader that basically calls `dotnet <myapp.dll>`, even if publishing a framework-dependent application. That's why even a program that is targeting AnyCpu needs a platform-dependent publish step.

[Note: On Windows, the exe file might already be created in the build step, as VS uses it. But you'll notice that it always has about the same size, for all your apps.]

Comment: Sorry, still not get, why I must specify target runtime :) Can't the stub loader be Any CPU?

But one more thing — I have tried `dotnet publish`, and it allows to publish framework-dependent version without specifying runtime — and throws an error if I try to do the same with self-contained flag. So it might be just the GUI problem?..

Comment: The stub loader is an operating-system dependent native app. It is a (small) application that is written for that particular OS and CPU, since .NET binaries cannot be directly run on a CPU. They need an "interpreter", and that interpreter is the .NET runtime. But it must first be loaded in an operating-system dependent way.

Comment: `dotnet publish` without target probably just publishes for the current platform, implicitly assuming that's what you want. The GUI is just more explicit in that it does not have a "default" option.

Comment: But why then when I press "publish" on Any CPU app on .Net Framework 4.8 — it did not ask nothing about target runtime? :)

Comment: .NET Framework is completely different. It only runs on Windows, and "Any CPU" there only means it can run on both 32bit and 64bit CPUs. With the X86/X64 setting in .NET Framework, you can only specify whether the application should run in 32 bit or 64 bit mode. If it is set to AnyCPU, it uses 32 bits only if the target computer cannot run 64 bit apps.

Comment: Yes, but... Well, my question is this, I suppose — before I build the Release build with Any CPU option on .Net Framework, pack the Release folder an publish it, and supposed, that it will run without a problem on x86 and x64. What should I do now, with .Net 5? Should I create 2 packages, one win-x86 and one win-x64? Should I get an x86 OS to try the x86 package, or Any CPU still guarantee non-problem working, if the build works on my x64 OS?

Comment: You can either publish for both, or only for x86 if your application does not benefit from 64 bit support (that means if it does not use large amounts of memory). 32 bit apps will run on 64 bit Windows, but not the other way round. You can also consider only publishing for 64 bit, since 32 bit Windows computers are dying out. Very few people will still need that.

Comment: Should I worry about working of my Any CPU build, that working on a x64 OS, on a x86 system? If I implicitly set the target runtime as `x86` during publish?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that last question. An x64 OS cannot be installed on a x86 system.

Comment: With the "Any CPU" configuration on .Net Framework I believed that my app will work on x86 and x64 without problems — because nothing stated otherwise. Should I get an x86 OS to check it now, when with .Net 5 I'm going to get two separate packages, for x86 and for x64?

Comment: To make sure, you could use an x86 VM to check, but it's very unlikely there will be any problems. If the X86 version works on the X64 computer, it is quite certain that it will work on pure X86, too.